# How can I create a button on excel that automatically moves me to a specific row?

Tags: excel

My excel sheet has a lot of rows where I go over different problems. Is there a way to create a drop down menu at the top of my sheet that can automatically take me to a specific row depending on what problem I want to look at?

I know how to create a drop down menu with all of the problem names, but I don't know how to link each name in the drop down menu to a specific row number to move the screen down.

Comment: I would just use a named range for each of the cells in question and then use the "Named Ranges" drop down above the top left corner of the grid.  No code, no controls, just the built-in functionality of Excel.

Comment: A low-tech solution is to use named ranges. Then the name box functions like you want. This wouldn't be effective if you already use named ranges for other things. In that case, VBA is probably the way to go. It is annoying that Excel doesn't have a built-in navigation pane.